# Using URL variable to activate first option in dependent drop down and prompt OnChange event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

**Project Background:**
I have a functioning search form that has 5 dependent drop downs that are required to drill down the data. The first variable `dim_id` is selected on my `product_request` page and the `OnChange` sends the variable to my ajax handler to populate the next select `cap_id` with relevant data. This continues to happen, back and fourth until 5 parameters are selected and the sixth box `productnumber` is activated with only one option.

Overall, it functions perfectly if someone comes into this page cold.

**Where I hit the wall:**
Now we want to be able to come into this page carrying the `dim_id` in the url from a parent product page, so they can select their variations using the other four drop downs.

What I think needs to happen is the `dim_id` needs to be built into the url like this:

```
product_request.php?dim_id=1
```

And somehow jump start that process like this:

1) Making the proper selection in the first drop down

2) Automatically prompting the `OnChange` event to go to my Ajax handler to populate the second select box `cap_id` with relevant data

I'm sorry I don't have snippets of code, I honestly have no idea where to even begin in making this function happen.

Comment: if you don't have any idea hire someone to do this task, please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bear in mind this is one possible solution. You have suggested using URL parameters for the data transfer, which is a good idea. In PHP, the URL parameters are accessible through the `$_GET` superglobal.

In your example string, `http://example.com/product_request.php?dim_id=1`, you can access the parameter by accessing `$var = $_GET["dim_id"]`. If this parameter was set, you'd want to add the option into the first select box, either by simply echoing it in using PHP or scrolling through the list and selecting it using Javascript. You could then echo out some Javascript code calling your onChange handler for the select box, as if it was selected. This would make it prefill the second box with the values. A rough draft might look like this:

```
<?php 
    $have_dID = false;
    if (isset($_GET["dim_id"])) {
        $dID = $_GET["dim_id"]
        $have_dID = true;
    }
?>
<script>
    function someProcessingFunction() {
        // Make some ajax call based on value of #dim_id select box...
        // Add options from ajax call to #cap_1
        // Enable #cap_1
    }
</script>
<select id="dim_1" name="dim_1" onChange="someProcessingFunction()">
    <?php
    if ($have_dID) {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $dID; ?>">Parent option</option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<select id="cap_1" name="cap_1" disabled="disabled">
    <!-- Options to be filled by function -->
</select>
<?php
    if ($have_dID) {
        ?>
        <script> someProcessingFunction() </script>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: With this as a starting point, I created a simpler (for me) solution by using that variable in the URL in the select statement of the first drop down to return a single result that still requires the end user to "select" it. This prompts the function that populates the next drop down and everything else works accordingly. Works like a charm. Thank you